# What is an "invalid slice size" error in rails? - @categories.each_slice(column_length) do |column| Happens w/ this code.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

Getting "invalid slice size"

Brand new to rails. playing around on the front end.

```
- column_length = @categories.length.fdiv(3).ceil
- @categories.each_slice(column_length) do |column|
```

This code generates the error. It seems to be working fine on the running site. The only think I've done is edit the navs and bootstrap layout so far..

What could cause this error, which is keeping the page form rendering?

Comment: can you print the output of `@categories.length.fdiv(3)` in your console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I reproduced the error :

```
[1,2,3].each_slice(0.22222222).to_a
# ArgumentError: invalid slice size
[1,2,3].each_slice(0).to_a
# ArgumentError: invalid slice size
[1,2,3].each_slice(-1).to_a
# ArgumentError: invalid slice size
```

`#each_slice` will take its argument as `Fixnum` instances, except `0` or any **negative number**. `#each_slice` always tries to convert its argument to `Fixnum` by using [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method, and after doing that if it gets `0` or any **negative number**, it will throw you the error as you got. And if the *argument* to the `#each_slice` method can't be converted to *integer* , it will give you kind of below :

```
[1,2,3].each_slice([1]).to_a
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
[1,2,3].each_slice(Object.new).to_a
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Object into Integer
```

But you give it a `Float` point number like the below which after *type casting* give you a `Fixnum` instance, but not `0`, will work fine :

```
[1,2,3].each_slice(2.22222222).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [3]]
```

Now, in your case `@categories.length.fdiv(3).ceil` gives you something `0` or any **negative number**, and that argument value to the `#each_slice` causing the error.

Well, I found the `C` code for it from [official documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L2188)

```
static VALUE
enum_each_slice(VALUE obj, VALUE n)
{
    long size = NUM2LONG(n);
    VALUE ary;
    NODE *memo;
    int arity;

    if (size <= 0) rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "invalid slice size");
    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(obj, 1, &n, enum_each_slice_size);
    ary = rb_ary_new2(size);
    arity = rb_block_arity();
    memo = NEW_MEMO(ary, dont_recycle_block_arg(arity), size);
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, each_slice_i, (VALUE)memo);
    ary = memo->u1.value;
    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) > 0) rb_yield(ary);

    return Qnil;
}
```

So, Why `[1,2,3].each_slice(0.22222222).to_a` causing the error - `ArgumentError: invalid slice size` :

Well, you can see from the MRI source code that `n`(means `0.22222222`) has been passed to the function `NUM2LONG()`. Now, If you look at the [Rubinius implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-core-api/blob/master/lib/rubinius/kernel/common/type.rb#L71-L77) of the function, you will find

```
def self.num2long(obj)
  if obj == nil
    raise TypeError, "no implicit conversion from nil to integer"
  else
    Integer(obj)
  end
end
```

This code is very clearly telling, what's going on inside the `NUM2LONG()` function. Now, lets try the 3 examples `n` value, as I used in my top 3 examples to reproduce the error, in IRB :

```
Integer(0.22222) # => 0
Integer(-1) # => -1
Integer(0) # => 0
```

This is how, for `n = 0.22222`in MRI `size` is being assigned as `0` by the function `NUM2LONG(n)`. That *zero* value triggers the error.